# Actually waiting for a reaction with discord bot (Python)

Tags: python, events, discord.py, bots, python-asyncio

I am trying to actually let my bot wait till it receives a reaction on its message and meanwhile do nothing. Just waiting. First as soon as it receives the reaction it should continue with the rest of the code. Here is a (shitty) example code:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("waiting for players to join ...")
    for i in range(5):
        botMsg = await ctx.send("User X do you want to play?")
        await botMsg.add_reaction("✔️")
        await botMsg.add_reaction("❌")

        try:
            reaction, player = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=20, check=lambda reaction, player: reaction.emoji in ["✔️", "❌"])
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("No one reacted.")

        if client.user != player and reaction.emoji == "✔️":
            await ctx.send(f"{player.mention} reacted with ✔️.")
        elif client.user != player and reaction.emoji == "❌":
            await ctx.send(f"{player.mention} reacted with ❌.")
```

Excecuting this code ends up in a big mess without the bot waiting in between the messages. How can I implement that the bot waits for a reaction between every message without already sending all of the other ones?

I'd appreciate anyone's help

Comment: You can simply edit the original message, if that is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problems with the way you check the emojis... I'm not really sure :/

Anyways here's what I got working:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    for i in range(5):
        msg = await ctx.send("Waiting for reactions...")
        emojis = [u"\u2714", u"\u274C"]
        await msg.add_reaction(emojis[0])
        await msg.add_reaction(emojis[1])
        
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=20.0, check=lambda reaction, user: user.id != client.user.id and reaction.emoji in emojis)
            if reaction.emoji == emojis[0]:
                await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} said yes!")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} said no :(")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("You\'re out of time!")
```